# The last element of the flatList is blocked halfway in react native. How can I unblock this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react native app I got some thing like this

```
 --------------------------
 ||       Filter         ||
 ||       Filter         ||
 ||       Filter         ||
 ||       Filter         ||
 ||       Filter         ||
 ||       Filter         ||
 |------------------------|
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |       elements         |
 |        FlatList        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 --------------------------
```

As you can see in the above snippet I am displaying my `element` in the element `flatist area`.FlatList Vertical scroll

The thing is When the filter section is open, user can't see the whole of the
last element only the top part of this.

Here is the code of my `list page`

```
<View>
      <ProductFunctions
        openFilterList={openFilterList}
        setOpenFilterList={setOpenFilterList}
        filteredState={filteredState}
        setFilteredState={setFilteredState}
        filteredInfos={filteredInfos}
        setFilteredInfos={setFilteredInfos}
      />

      {filteredState === false ? (
        <FlatList
          data={dupFilteredList}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
          style={styles.arrayListMargin}
        />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={filteredInfos}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
          style={styles.arrayListMargin}
        />
      )}
    </View>
```

Here is the css of this page.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {marginVertical: 10},
  arrayListMargin: {marginBottom: 80},
  accordionText: {color: '#4684A0', fontSize: 18},
});
```

What changes should I make so that user is able to scroll until bottom half of the last element

Comment: Try to use a ScrollView instead of a normal View

Comment: @yesIamFaded Scrollview will make all the element in the list render and the performance goes down. Yeah it will works but the app is quite heavy right now. So

Comment: Are you using bottom navigation in your app??

Comment: @AnwerSolangi I am using drawernavigation only